# Verify in which adcampains, adcampain_groups, adset is used a CA custom audience

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-ads-api

Is possible to know (from a customAudienceId) in which AdCampain, AdCampainGroup and AdSet is used (or not) this CA?
Is also possible to select the graph /customaudiences specifying which ids I need to query?
Many thanks at all, Alex.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible to get the list of campaigns or ads given a CA. You can get the targeting info for all the adgroups and then check to see if the CA ID is present there.